# How do I make non-form elements line up along their bottom in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried searching for answers, but almost all search results involve lining up inputs to buttons using the .form-inline class. Here is a jsfiddle explaining my problem and what I want the outcome to be:

http://jsfiddle.net/u0o349he/

This seems like it should be a routine fix but I have obviously missed the lesson on how to align things in bootstrap. I know that I could use:

```
<h1>Big text <small>trailing comments</small></h1>
```

But for my purposes, I want to .text-right the right col (while maintaining the left alignment of the left col). So I can't think of any other way of doing this. This problem affects many areas of my project.

Comment: Please see this tutorial :http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

Comment: That does answer the question, but wow. It's incredible how much extra markup/code I need to write to line up a header with a paragraph.

Comment: Exactly there will be some more viable solution. I'm working on it

Comment: The inherent problem is that `h1` by default, even outside of BS has margin/greater size. That increases the size of the container (your blue part) and text lines up at the top of elements. Your text is aligned, just to the top, which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: @NicholasFolk :  I think you should use the hacky CSS and check it for different screen sizes if it remains responsive I don't think you should get worked up on this then

Comment: @sharf Yes, but even then, it's the top of the margins that are aligned, not even the top of the text itself (because as you said, the margin sizes are different). Bootstraps grid system provides amazing support for horizontal alignment, but it clearly has a limitation on its ability to manage vertical alignment...

Comment: That limitation is due to the way html works. Things are very easy to move and align horizontally, but there is very little support for vertical alignment, positioning, etc.

Comment: As @sharf said, the limitation is in HTML/CSS.